problem in running the docker container in windows
I'm trying to run the docker container in the windows desktop and I getting the error
PS C:\Users\hemal\Downloads\EatEasy_Food_Ordering_Website-main\EatEasy_Food_Ordering_Website-main> docker run -p 8080:8080 my-node-app

eateasy@1.0.0 start
node server.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1282
return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
^
Error: /usr/src/app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1282:18)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1100:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
at Object. (/usr/src/app/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1198:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12) {
code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
